# How to create discord Embed's in chat?

Tags: discord.js

I have the following command called `say` that generates an embed with the following syntax: `!say hello, It's a test,#000000`.

It works just fine, but the problem is that I want it to be easier to create embed's so that any privileged user could create an embed without knowing the syntax of the command and make it easier to me to maintain all the camps the embed can handle without needing to assign them to variables.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
    let [Title,Description,Color] = args;
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(Color)
    .setTitle(Title)
    .setDescription(Description)

    msg.channel.send(embed);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "embed"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to achieve that would be to use the privilege of the [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) accepting object as data.

So my solution would have this syntax:

```
!say {
  "title": "hello",
  "description": "It's a test",
  "color": 000000
}
```

and many other properties that [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) can take.

> Useful links:
> **[Embed builder](https://embedbuilder.nadekobot.me/)**

The code behind that will handle our arguments and transform them into an embed

```js
const rawJson = args.join(" ") || "";

let json = {};
try {
  json = JSON.parse(rawJson);
} catch (err) {
  message.reply(`${err}`);
}
if (!json) return;

const content = json.content || json.text || json.plainText || "";
//In case the thumbnail comes as a string {json.thumbnail = "test.com/image.png"} so we assign it into the url of the thumbnail
if (typeof json.thumbnail === "string") {
  json.thumbnail = { url: json.thumbnail };
}
//Same here
if (typeof json.image === "string") {
  json.image = { url: json.image };
}

message.channel.send(content, { embed: json }).catch((err) => {
  message.reply(`${err}`)
});
```