# Split args Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to `split` args **not** just by spaces. I'm trying to have spaces into my different args for creating a dynamic embed.

> '!embed Title;Author;Description'

But my code actually sent command ("embed") as first argument ("Title"). How can I prevent that?

'message' event:

```
let input = message.content;
let prefix = input[0];
let command = input.substr(1).split(' ')[0];
let args = command.substr( command.indexOf(' ') + 1 );
```

command:

```
args = args.split(';').map(elem => elem.trim());
let [autor, titulo, texto] = args;
message.channel.send(
   new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(autor, '')
      .setTitle(titulo)
      .setDescription("\n\n"+texto)
      .setColor("000000")
);
```

Comment: check this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/66660875/10675707) answer maybe this help's you with what you're trying to achieve (not the answer for this question)

Comment: Not just for embed, I want to do that for other commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the `message content` into the actual `command` and the `args` like this:

```js
const input = "!myCommand my first arg;arg2;arg3";
const args = input.slice(1).substring(input.indexOf(' ')).split(';');
const command = input.slice(1).split(' ').splice(0, 1)[0];

console.log(`Command: ${command}`);
console.log('Args: ' + args);
```

---

### References

- [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
- [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do. I want to Title string could contain spaces, for example, so split arguments by spaces is not a way.

Comment: You could split the `args` by spaces and if you need space in **one** argument you could use a **underscore**, e.g. `!embed This_is_my_title;Author;Description`. You can then replace the underscores with spaces afterwards.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021540/discord-js-arguments-with-spaces)

Comment: I saw it before ask in this topic. Using that, command (in this case, anuncio) is recognised as only argument and other arguments are just ignored.
So the embed looks like this https://i.imgur.com/UTYF5bo.png

Comment: Hmmm okay... try this: `msg.content.split(' ').splice(1).join(' ')`

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: It will split the message up into an array, remove the first value and then join the remaining values. So this will set your `args`

Comment: Nope, still not working. Now it take every character as single arg. https://i.imgur.com/6IShkBU.png

Comment: Okay I think I got it now, sorry: `const args = input.slice(1).substring(input.indexOf(' ')).split(';')` This should return an `array` containing all your `args` even if they contain a `space`

Comment: No problem :) I adjusted my answer and added the code for getting only the command too, just in case you need it